# Precompute hashCode for value-based classes?

Tags: java, hashcode

Value-based classes have the property that they

> are final and immutable (though may contain references to mutable objects).

Consequently, if you know that your object only contains immutable instances, you could precompute the `hashCode` of the instance. This could speed up access when using `Map` or `Set` operations.

Looking at the implementation of `hashCode` from `Instant`, which is a value-based class, why have the developers decided against this pattern? Would the loss of performance for precomputing the `hashCode` be more significant than computing it over and over again when required?

```
// copied from Instant#hashCode
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return ((int) (seconds ^ (seconds >>> 32))) + 51 * nanos;
}
```

So, **under what condition is precomputing** the `hashCode` justified?

Comment: That example looks so simple to compute that it's not worth the complexity of saving it.  By contrast, consider a class with many fields (all of which are folded into the hash).  Note in general I would not 'precompute', I'd compute on first use - no need to have a hash value if the object is never stored in a hashed structure.

Comment: Consider `java.lang.String`. It does cache it's hashcode.

Comment: I would only do it if you can show that precomputing it gives a clear performance improvement in your specific scenario. Precomputing costs resources (cpu time and memory overhead) for all objects of that specific class, even if the `hashCode` is never used. For complex objects it might make sense to calculate the `hashCode` on the first call and cache it for further use.

Comment: Neither does BigInteger nor BigDecimal.  Imo, if the value is likely to be used as a key to a  map then it would pay to precompute the hashcode.  But there is usually a judgment call based on whether it is reasonable to do so.  At one time, String's hashcode was not precomputed but later analysis proved it would be beneficial.  Also keep in mind that immutable classes like BigX  would continually do this for all computations internally. as they return new instances of themselves.  For those classes that could be expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't straight-forward reason why `Instant` doesn't cache `hashcode`. But some that I could think of:

Caching `hashcode` comes at a price: the instance variable declared:

- It of-course occupies more memory per object. It may be alright to re-compute the hashcode, than allocate extra memory for every instance object
- Worry about serialization/deserialization, as the instance variable would need to be preserved. Increasing the size of the serialized object
- The internal implementation becomes difficult to be modified in future versions. Especially more so because of past serialized objects. Preserving backward compatibility becomes difficult for past version objects. Extra maintenance.
- `hashcode` may never be called on an Instant object. In such a case, we waste CPU in computing something that is never used

So may not make sense to cache. May be it makes sense for `String` as it is so commonly used throughout. May be worth the headache.